# Trying to upload a usdz file using vb.net but content type incorrect. Is this an encoding problem?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I am trying to upload a usdz file to a website using vb.net. I am using the following code

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
wc.UploadFile("https://filebin.net/" + id + "/model.usdz", "C:\Windows\Temp\model.usdz")
```

When I go to the website the file is there, but the file's content type is stated as `application/octet-stream` and the file does not open correctly.

When I upload through the website the content is stated as `application/zip` and it works fine.

How do I change the content type to `application/zip`?

I have tried adding `wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/zip")` but still not working

Comment: The code was better before the edit. You where correct to have a `Using` block there.

Comment: I noticed with the `Using` block is was failing to upload after including the `wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/zip")`

Comment: Use HttpClient to Post a `ByteArrayContent`

Comment: Thanks Jimi. That worked a treat. I will post the answer when I get in tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi for this one.

```
'Create a request to the target URL
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(targetUrl), 
HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"

'Set the content type and length
request.ContentType = "application/zip"
request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length

'Get the request stream and write the byte array
Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
requestStream.Close()

'Get the response from the server
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), 
HttpWebResponse)

'Read and print the response
Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
        Dim responseText As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).